# How can I set my Windows 7 Phone's default DNS server?

Tags: settings, wifi, 7.x

I have a strange issue with my internet connection, where people coming over to my house are *sometimes* unable to connect to the internet.  On my own computers I have also experienced the issue, but I have found that changing the default DNS server on a device will allow it to work (such as to google's 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4).  My wireless will alternate between working normally and requiring a different DNS server, often for days, possibly weeks at a time.  I have investigated changing this on my router/modem, but there is no interface to change this in the router/modem settings.

With my desktops, laptops, TVs and DVD players, this all works fine, as they all have an option to change the DNS server used.  However with my Windows 7 Phone there seems to be no option to set the DNS server in Settings -> Wi-Fi.  This is quite troublesome for me, as I can only use the phone with wireless (no phone plan).  My question is as follows:

Is there any application, or existing interface to allow me to change the default DNS Server on my phone?

As a side question, I'm also curious: Why didn't/wouldn't Microsoft choose to include this functionality, which appears to be on every other recent wireless device?

**EDIT**:

[My router](http://www.rosewill.com/Mgnt/Uploads2/AttachmentForProduct/UserManual-RNX-N4PS%20Version1.0.pdf) doesn't seem to have any options to configure DHCP for a specific DNS server, and the only option to configure the DNS server is by using a static IP.  I tried using the current IP and other settings for a static IP, but I lost my connection after a day or so.

Comment: Consider contacting your IPS to let them know their DNS is unresponsive at times.

Comment: What make and model of router?

Comment: @WayneInML It's a Rosewill RNX-N4PS (the user manual: http://www.rosewill.com/Mgnt/Uploads2/AttachmentForProduct/UserManual-RNX-N4PS%20Version1.0.pdf ).

Comment: Hmm, I would ditch the router unless there is a reason to stick with it. Can't assign a DNS and doesn't look like dd-wrt or openwrt will work with it. Just my opinion, YMMV. I have a dual-band Linksys N router, using OpenDNS with it, works great great.

Comment: @WayneInML Yeah, I've been considering doing that.  I just wish that my phone not working because of my ISP's DNS sucking didn't mean I need a new router.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the DNS servers through DHCP.

Microsoft aims on simplicity, and it's fairly safe to assume that either DHCP or a statically leased IP is available in every occasion. If an administrator doesn't turn on DHCP, he most doesn't want phones on his network unless he explicitly configures them as static leases...

Comment: I'll need to do some research on this, thanks!

Comment: @Darthfett My guess is that your wireless station should have it as an option in configuration.

Comment: Most routers should have a configurable DNS servers.

Comment: I've gone through [my router's user manual](http://www.rosewill.com/Mgnt/Uploads2/AttachmentForProduct/UserManual-RNX-N4PS%20Version1.0.pdf) with no luck.  See my edit -- only static IP enables a custom DNS, and I don't have a static IP.

Comment: @Darthfett: Indeed, seems you can't set it for the LAN side... :(

Comment: @WayneInML: Please place your comment on the question, only I received a notification but I'm not the right person to answer that... :(